# Compiled query using list of class objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Can somebody help me out in creating compiled queries where input is to be a list of class objects? I have seen examples where `Func<DataContext, somematchobject, IQueryable<T>>` is created and compiled.
But can I do something like `Func<List<T>, matchObject, T>`, and compile it?
Basically I want an `object(T)` meeting certain conditions (as in matchObject) to be returned from a list of `objects(List<T>)`.

Will `CompiledQuery.Compile` help me in this? 
Please help me experts!!

Comment: Can you provide some more input. Maybe some source code what you are trying to do. Are you trying Linq to object or Linq to Sql?.

Answer (score 0):

```
var selected = from item in list
               where item.Matches(matchObject)
               select item;
```

or

```
var selected = list.Where(item => item.Matches(matchObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a Func, matchObject, T> Fn (say). And built an 
Expression,matchObject,T>> Ex (say) where I gave the match conditions.
And Fn = Ex.Compile(), and its done. 
Whenever  I want a particular object I would create a matchObject and call
Fn(List, matchObject), it would return me my T object. 
Thanks for all your help!!